# Why is `min_by` and `max_by` return `Option<T>` in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have recently started learning Rust, and I have seen that the methods `min_by` and `max_by` on iterators return an `Option<T>`. Why is this the case? When will it return `None`?

Comment: what happen if the iterator is empty? what would be the minimum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When iterators are **empty** there are no values to check:

```
fn main() {
    let slice: &[u8] = &[];
    println!("{:?}", slice.iter().max());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9d605fe7dbc9f594dff41b5aa6d13397)

You can check it in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by)

Comment: So I understand that it returns an `Option` instead of just `panic`-ing. Why choose to do so?

Comment: @nirshahar why would you panic for something like that? It is not an irrecuperable error....

Comment: I guess so. Thanks! This simple thing didn't cross my mind really :o

Comment: @nirshahar not always but usually rust APIs try to avoid panicing, and instead leave that to the consumer of the API. This allows the caller to handle the condition as they see fit, and makes it usable in situations where panics are unacceptable.

Comment: @nirshahar To expand on what Masklinn wrote, a panic is just an `.unwrap()` away - change `iter.max()` with `iter.max().unwrap()`, and there you have it. (Except the use of `unwrap()` makes it *explicit* that you're panicking on empty iterator.)